# What is the best way to do a arrow button?

Tags: html, css, button

I'm trying to create an arrow button like the upvote here in stackoverflow (http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=5).

The only difference is when I hover the mouse over the arrow, it will change the background image.

I need something like this http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/, but with background image, instead of RGB color.

What is the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know your background color, you can get sneaky.  For example, if the background of the page is white...

**HTML**

```
<div id="arrow">
```

**CSS**

```
#arrow {
  width: 0;
  border: 40px solid white;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  background-image: url('...');
  background-position: -40px 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 80px;
}
```

You'll have to munge with the background position and size properties to get exactly the effect you want.

Comment: Whoops, right you are.  I've updated the answer with a few tweaks, as well as the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LBBGe/2/.

Comment: thanks man... good joob! Another doubt ... How can I rotate this arrow? Could you please give me the example of up, down, left, right arrows?

Comment: You can change the `border-bottom-color` part to control what side the arrow shows up on.  For example, to have a left-facing arrow, use `border-right-color: transparent` instead.  You'll probably also have to adjust the background position again.